# Enum class performance when array indexing

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, enums

Can I expect to see a performance hit for the casting in this  . .

```
enum class myEnum {A,B,C};
myArray[(int)myEnum::A] = 123;
```

Compared to this?

```
enum myEnum {A,B,C};
myArray[A] = 123;
```

I'm leaning towards the new style enum classes for the type safety, but don't want to do it at the expense of performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends whether the enum value used as an index is known at compile time or passed in a variable.

That is `myArray[(int)myEnum::A]` shall not incur any penalty but `myArray[(int)e]` might, depending on the physical representation of `e` (ie, it might be necessary to "extend" it).

On the other hand, a simple extension is a trivial operation that is unlikely to ever show up as a performance issues: things like branch prediction (in conditionals) and caching are much more important in most applications (for low-level), and at a higher level algorithms matter.

*Note: to avoid the extension issue in the runtime scenario, you could define the base type of `myEnum` to be the natural type that is expected for compiler arithmetic, I believe a `ptrdiff_t` would be most appropriate here. It is a big integer though.*

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's ultimately up to the compiler, but it's hard to see why any reasonable compiler would generate different code in these two cases.

I've tested this with g++ 4.7.2 on Intel, and they compile to identical assembly code.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not likely that the casting should have any impact on performance. This is all resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect NOT, but it would depend on the compiler implementation. Why don't you try both approaches, and time it? Try a few different compiler optimisation settings too, so you know that it won't make it different when it comes to production code compiles.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there would be any assembly instructions at all for the cast, since the entire expression `(int)myEnum::A` can be evaluated at compile time.

But if you really want to know, make a pair of sample programs, and analyze both by dumping disassembly, and/or measuring performance.